# (clojure testing) Configure leiningen to run tests inside src (not only in the test directory)

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, leiningen

When writing tests I like to use both tests defined with `deftest` and placed inside the test directory, and tests defined with `with-test` and placed next to the function definition in the src directory.

I use `deftest` for tests that require complicated setup and would be quite messy to define next to the function under test.

I use `with-test` for testing functions with simple input parameters.

I am able to run the tests defined in the source by running the `(run-tests)` macro.

I run the `deftest` tests with `lein test`.

Is there a way to configure `lein test` to also pick up all the tests in the src directory (the `with-test` tests)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to add the `src` into list of `:test-paths` in project definition?

Comment: Thank you, setting `:test-paths ["test" "src"]` in the porject.clj file added all tests from src to the tests run by leiningen.